# VSCode Launch.json configuration cannot start:desktop -- --app excel fails error 1 for Excel Office-Addin

Tags: javascript, excel, visual-studio-code, office-js, office-addins

Following the tutorial [Tutorial Create an Excel Addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial).

Have completed and tested the first section of the tutorial using the command line.

Trying to use the debugger in vscode to run and debug taskpane.js using **Excel Desktop(Edge Legacy)**.

It fails with below debug error which in short is *missing script: start:desktop -- --app excel*
This was a closed issue for vscode 1.53.0 [Issue 115876](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115876). Reading this however I am unsure how to update launch.json to resolve it.

I am using VSCODE **1.64.1**

This is my config for Excel Desktop (Edge Legacy)

```
 {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Legacy)",
      "type": "office-addin",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=Excel$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
      "port": 9222,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
    },
```

Debug Output

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start:desktop -- --app excel'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start:desktop -- --app excel
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:282:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\PC_User\office_projects\My Office Add-in
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start:desktop -- --app excel"
8 verbose node v14.17.3
9 verbose npm  v6.14.13
10 error missing script: start:desktop -- --app excel
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**Edit**
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "office-addin-taskpane-js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-JS.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "app_to_debug": "excel",
    "app_type_to_debug": "desktop",
    "dev_server_port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "lint": "office-addin-lint check",
    "lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
    "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.180",
    "@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.17",
    "acorn": "^8.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-office-addins": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.3.5",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^4.3.8",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.7.7",
    "office-addin-lint": "^2.0.0",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.7.7",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.1.4",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.50.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.7.3"
  },
  "prettier": "office-addin-prettier-config",
  "browserslist": [
    "ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you specify the Excel version you have got installed on the problematic machine?

Comment: Did you try `npm run start:desktop -- --app excel` in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to create a new Excel add-in according to your description and run it under the debugger. Everything went well without issues. But I've used the `Edge (Chromium)` option in the launch section.

It seems the `package.json` file doesn't contain a corresponding command in the `scripts` section, the following error message clearly states about that:

```
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start:desktop -- --app excel
```

I'd suggest generating a new add-in project using yeoman generator and checking the scripts section there. Don't forget to update the yeoman itself.

For example, in Outlook add-ins I see the following command in the scripts section:

```
"start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
```

Comment: I have updated yeoman and reinstall the office generator which is at version generator-office@1.8.1. In the new package.json I have     "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",  "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",

Comment: Still receiving > Executing task: npm run "start:desktop -- --app excel" <

npm ERR! missing script: start:desktop -- --app excel

Comment: How does the `package.json` look like in the project where you are trying to run the add-in under the debugger attached?

Comment: Do you have the `office-addin-debugging` package installed?

Comment: I have the Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger v0.2.0 installed, I have added package.json contents to the Question details

Comment: What error do you get now? Does a newly created/generated add-in work correclty?

Comment: The error remains the same. Yo updated, vs-code on latest version. The addins work as per the tutorial. But the debugger in vscode will not work because of Error: missing script: start:desktop -- --app excel

Comment: Do you get the same error message with a newly created/generated add-i n project?

Comment: Yes I do with a new project

Comment: You can post this as an issue to the https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office repo.

Comment: I've just tried to create a new Excel add-in according to your description and run it under the debugger. Everything went well without issues. But I've used the `Edge (Chromium)` option in the launch section.

Comment: Thanks, there must be something unique in my setup althuogh I have ensured everything is updated.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP, you have added the config for `launch.json` but haven't mentioned anything about [`tasks.json`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane/blob/master/.vscode/tasks.json). The `preLaunchTask` & `postDebugTask` in your config is looking for config in `tasks.json` which should look something like below.

Based on the debug output you added, this is the most likely issue, since this is where you need the script `start:desktop -- --app excel`

```json
    {
      "label": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start:desktop -- --app excel",
      "presentation": {
        "clear": true,
        "panel": "dedicated",
      },

    {
      "label": "Stop Debug",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "stop",
      "presentation": {
        "clear": true,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
```

---

### Alternative reference from OLD version

Found a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68443) which mentions you can use below code. This is a older discussion though.

They also point to a template GitHub Repository for [Office-Addin-TaskPane](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane/blob/954f8f252c8b3ca8e2d97de2de9d31d0e2c5ec7f/.vscode/launch.json) by Microsoft which has the launch.json

```json
{
  "name": "Excel Desktop",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
  "runtimeArgs": ["run", "start", "desktop"],
  "args": ["--", "--app", "excel"]
},
```